# Cannot remove array if compared value appear in another layer

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove the redundant array under "allPolicies" by matching it using the parent 'policy' field:

This is my existing Array Object:

```
{
"all": [{
    "policy": "XH123",
    "allDependants": [{
        "dependant": "dependantA",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH123",
            "policyName": "XH123 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }, {
            "policy": "XH1234",
            "policyName": "XH1234 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }, {
        "dependant": "dependantB",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH123",
            "policyName": "XH123 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }, {
            "policy": "XH1234",
            "policyName": "XH1234 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "policy": "XH1234",
    "allDependants": [{
        "dependant": "dependantA",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH123",
            "policyName": "XH123 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }, {
            "policy": "XH1234",
            "policyName": "XH1234 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }, {
        "dependant": "dependantB",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH123",
            "policyName": "XH123 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }, {
            "policy": "XH1234",
            "policyName": "XH1234 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

The end result would be like this:

```
{
"all": [{
    "policy": "XH123",
    "allDependants": [{
        "dependant": "dependantA",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH123",
            "policyName": "XH123 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }, {
        "dependant": "dependantB",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH123",
            "policyName": "XH123 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "policy": "XH1234",
    "allDependants": [{
        "dependant": "dependantA",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH1234",
            "policyName": "XH1234 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }, {
        "dependant": "dependantB",
        "allPolicies": [{
            "policy": "XH1234",
            "policyName": "XH1234 Name",
            "coverage": "ALL"
        }]
    }]
}]
}
```

What I attempted was using nested forEach loop like so:

```js
var allClone = Object.assign({}, all);

all.all.forEach(function (currentPolicy, currentPolicyIndex, currentPolicyArray) {
    currentPolicy.allDependants.forEach(function (dependant, dependantIndex, dependantArray) {
        dependant.allPolicies.forEach(function (dpolicy, dpolicyIndex, dpolicyArray) {
            if (dpolicy.PolicyNo === currentPolicy.PolicyNo) {
                allClone.all[currentPolicyIndex].allDependants[dependantIndex].allPolicies = dpolicy //should just be one result
            }
        })
    });
});
```

But it end up the data got mix up, XH1234 appears in XH123 or vice versa.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I have tried other methods mainly using .filter and .forEach and looping them at different level but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do that.

```js
 var data = { "all": [{ "policy": "XH123", "allDependants": [{ "dependant": "dependantA", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }, { "dependant": "dependantB", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }] }, { "policy": "XH1234", "allDependants": [{ "dependant": "dependantA", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }, { "dependant": "dependantB", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }] }] };

var result = {
  "all": data.all.map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      "allDependants": item.allDependants.map(value => {
        return {
          ...value,
          "allPolicies": value.allPolicies.filter(obj => obj.policy === item.policy)
        };
      })
    };
  })
}

console.log(result);
```

**ES5 solution without spread operator:**

```js
var data = { "all": [{ "policy": "XH123", "allDependants": [{ "dependant": "dependantA", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }, { "dependant": "dependantB", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }] }, { "policy": "XH1234", "allDependants": [{ "dependant": "dependantA", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }, { "dependant": "dependantB", "allPolicies": [{ "policy": "XH123", "policyName": "XH123 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }, { "policy": "XH1234", "policyName": "XH1234 Name", "coverage": "ALL" }] }] }] };

var result = {
  "all": data.all.map(item => {
    return {
      "policy": item.policy,
      "allDependants": item.allDependants.map(value => {
        return {
          "dependant": value.dependant,
          "allPolicies": value.allPolicies.filter(obj => obj.policy === item.policy)
        };
      })
    };
  })
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, is there an ES5 solution where I don't need to use the ... operator?

Comment: @Vincent1989 - Looks like Object.assign() also needs ES6. I will try to come up with a ES5 solution and update the answer soon.

Comment: Thats ok, I could use polyfill for Object.assign() to work. Thanks for the details code work, appreaciate a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome @Vincent1989. I just updated the answer with ES5 solution.